# Ctrl+B - Smoothing problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6X9YjsR5wSA

As seen on the video, when demonstrating smoothing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, notice that on the back (when dragging the mouse), the inner circle stays a perfect circle. 1:45 - 2:00 mins

When I do it, the inner circle turns in to an oval when I drag the mouse and as I drag it further the edges of the oval eventually overlap.

[image]
Does this sound familiar?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't recreate that behaviour. Can you record what you're doing, make a .gif and post it here?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gzBJR.   I didn't change any setting from a new file either and have started multiple new ones for testing purposes. I'm really excited about taking on blender but this is in my way. I have another issue that collides with this tutorial. But one problem at a time.

Comment: It's obvious,that something is wrong, but I can't tell what by the image. Can you upload the .blend using [this site](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: The file is up.

Comment: The answer from TobiasE is correct one.

Comment: @ICBlender If my answer solved your problem, please accept it so the question gets marked as solved. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have scaled the mesh in Object Mode and did not apply the scale before entering Edit Mode. To make the bevel operation work as you expect it to:

1. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to exit Edit Mode.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, select "Scale".
3. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter Edit Mode again.

Comment: That's exactly it.